# Use same Python variable in multiple if-statements

Tags: python, if-statement, raspberry-pi, global-variables, bottle

I am having issues with my current Python script. The purpose of the 'progress' variable is take a specific value when it goes through one of the if-loops. But, the program never goes further then the first if-statement. It looks as if every if-statement makes his own variable called 'progress'. Can someone please help me?
See code below.

```
from bottle import run, route, template, error, static_file     
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO                         
import time                             

switch1 = 21        
switch2 = 20        
switch3 = 26        
switch4 = 16        
switch5 = 19        

led1 = 13       
led2 = 12       
led3 = 6        
led4 = 5        
led5 = 25       

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)                          

GPIO.setup(switch1, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)          
GPIO.setup(switch2, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)          
GPIO.setup(switch3, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)          
GPIO.setup(switch4, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)          
GPIO.setup(switch5, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)          

GPIO.setup(led1, GPIO.OUT)                      
GPIO.setup(led2, GPIO.OUT)                      
GPIO.setup(led3, GPIO.OUT)                      
GPIO.setup(led4, GPIO.OUT)                      
GPIO.setup(led5, GPIO.OUT)                      


@route("/")
def hello():
    progress = 0
    while True:
        if progress == 0:
            GPIO.output(led1, False)
            GPIO.output(led2, False)
            GPIO.output(led3, False)
            GPIO.output(led4, False)
            GPIO.output(led5, False)

            progress = 1    
            return template('index.html')

        if (not GPIO.input(switch1)) and progress == 1:     
            GPIO.output(led1, True)
            progress = 2
            return template('video1.html')

        elif (not GPIO.input(switch2)) and progress == 2:   
            GPIO.output(led1, False)
            GPIO.output(led2, True)
            progress = 3
            return template('video2.html')

        elif (not GPIO.input(switch3)) and progress == 3:   
            GPIO.output(led2, False)
            GPIO.output(led3, True)
            progress = 4
            return template('video3.html')

        elif (not GPIO.input(switch4)) and progress == 4:   
            GPIO.output(led3, False)
            GPIO.output(led4, True)
            progress = 5
            return template('video4.html')

        elif (not GPIO.input(switch5)) and progress == 5:   
            GPIO.output(led4, False)
            GPIO.output(led5, True)
            progress = 6
            return template('video5.html')

        elif progress == 6:
            while True:                     
                GPIO.output(led1, True)
                GPIO.output(led2, True)
                GPIO.output(led3, True)
                GPIO.output(led4, True)
                GPIO.output(led5, True)
                time.sleep(0.5)
                GPIO.output(led1, False)
                GPIO.output(led2, False)
                GPIO.output(led3, False)
                GPIO.output(led4, False)
                GPIO.output(led5, False)
                time.sleep(0.5)

                return template('succes.html')

        elif GPIO.input(switch1) and GPIO.input(switch2) and GPIO.input(switch3) and GPIO.input(switch4) and GPIO.input(switch5):
             time.sleep(0.15)  


        else:                           
            GPIO.output(led1, False)
            GPIO.output(led2, False)
            GPIO.output(led3, False)
            GPIO.output(led4, False)
            GPIO.output(led5, False)

            return template('false.html')

        time.sleep(0.05)                    

@route('/<filename>')                           
def server_static(filename):
    return static_file(filename, root='static')

@error(404)                             
def error404(error):
    return("Nothing here, keep searching!")

run(host='0.0.0.0', port=80)
```

Comment: The initial assignment `progress == 0` should be `progress = 0`

Comment: That is because you have elif which prevents the code entering the block. Change the elif to if

Comment: I see, I copied the wrong code. Thanks for noticing!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are using `if...elif...`. Python will pick **one** matching test (the first `if` or `elif` test to match), and never run the other branches.

Thus, altering `progress` in one of those branches will not cause one of the other branches to then be picked.

If the tests are to be separate, you should not use `elif` but `if` for each branch.

However, you exit the view altogether in each branch with a `return` statement. Your function will *not continue*, the loop is exited and the next request will *always* start at the beginning again (where you set `progress = 0`. If `progress` is meant to be a global state in your server, you should set it as such. Do note that that is not going to be thread safe, nor is that variable going to be shared across processes if you use a WSGI server that uses multiprocessing to scale.

Since you are controlling a piece of hardware, using a global may be fine, but you need to then constrain your WSGI server to run just the one thread, or you need to use locking to limit this view to one thread at a time.

To make the `progress` global, add `global progress` at the top of your function, and put `progress = 0` *outside* the function:

```
progress = 0

@route("/")
def hello():
    global progress
    if progress == 0:
        GPIO.output(led1, False)
        GPIO.output(led2, False)
        GPIO.output(led3, False)
        GPIO.output(led4, False)
        GPIO.output(led5, False)

        progress = 1    
        return template('index.html')

    if (not GPIO.input(switch1)) and progress == 1:     
        GPIO.output(led1, True)
        progress = 2
        return template('video1.html')

    elif (not GPIO.input(switch2)) and progress == 2:   
        GPIO.output(led1, False)
        GPIO.output(led2, True)
        progress = 3
        return template('video2.html')

    elif (not GPIO.input(switch3)) and progress == 3:   
        GPIO.output(led2, False)
        GPIO.output(led3, True)
        progress = 4
        return template('video3.html')

    elif (not GPIO.input(switch4)) and progress == 4:   
        GPIO.output(led3, False)
        GPIO.output(led4, True)
        progress = 5
        return template('video4.html')

    elif (not GPIO.input(switch5)) and progress == 5:   
        GPIO.output(led4, False)
        GPIO.output(led5, True)
        progress = 6
        return template('video5.html')

    elif progress == 6:
        while True:                     
            GPIO.output(led1, True)
            GPIO.output(led2, True)
            GPIO.output(led3, True)
            GPIO.output(led4, True)
            GPIO.output(led5, True)
            time.sleep(0.5)
            GPIO.output(led1, False)
            GPIO.output(led2, False)
            GPIO.output(led3, False)
            GPIO.output(led4, False)
            GPIO.output(led5, False)
            time.sleep(0.5)

            return template('succes.html')

    elif GPIO.input(switch1) and GPIO.input(switch2) and GPIO.input(switch3) and GPIO.input(switch4) and GPIO.input(switch5):
         time.sleep(0.15)  


    else:                           
        GPIO.output(led1, False)
        GPIO.output(led2, False)
        GPIO.output(led3, False)
        GPIO.output(led4, False)
        GPIO.output(led5, False)

        return template('false.html')
```

Note that the `while` loop and the `sleep()` call are gone. You'll have to put Javascript in the responses instead to reload the page after a timeout instead.

Comment: I changed the elif-statements to if-statements. But, it didn't solve the problem. It still won't go pass the first if-statement.

Comment: @TimonBakker: no, because you exited the view function with a `return` statement.

Comment: The webpage is designed so that it will reload the script every 0.2 seconds. Is it that way still a problem that there is a return statement?

Comment: @TimonBakker: you cannot put a loop in a Bottle view function no. Have the *web browser* load a new page each time. You could put the state of the browser in a request variable and vary what page is returned in that case, but since you are also controlling hardware (of which there is only ever one, a hardwired global variable) you may as well put the `progress` variable as a global too.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Can you please explain how I can use a global variable in my script?

Answer (score 0):

Isn't the `return template('index.html')` exiting the function? Since you initialize the `progress` variable always to o the first if is always executed and exits at the end.

You must do the initialisation of your GPIO.output in a separate function and then you can test on the value of your GPIO.input. No need for the `progress` variable.

Answer (score 0):

As per bottle documentation `return template('')` will return the template and stop  the that  function in this "/"

The variable `progress` is a local variable you have not assigned any the variable inside the program other than initializing

you have assigned it to `0` so all the time the first `if` statement will be executed

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Do you have an idea how I can program the file so it will work the way I want?

Comment: Thnx for your answer. Is it possible with a global variable? Can you please explain how to program this the right way?

Comment: From where do you get the input for progress bar @TimonBakker